# Access denied for all users after MariaDb upgrade

Tags: freebsd, mariadb, upgrade

I discovered this morning that `MariaDb` had been removed from my server in the process of upgrading from FreeBSD 10.3 to 11.1. After getting the database engine reinstalled, and resolving the problems with `my.cnf` incompatibility, I finally got `MariaDb` working - except that now *every* user (other than root) is denied access to their database.

I tried resetting the password for a random user, but that didn't make any difference.

Where is there useful information about what's going wrong here?   This is all the information that's in the `server.err` after restarting the database:

```
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 2G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 25246709
2018-03-10 11:45:00 37094309376 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/db/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-03-10 11:45:00 37094309376 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180310 11:45:00
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2018-03-10 11:45:00 34424848384 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.2.13-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  FreeBSD Ports
2018-03-10 11:45:12 37180893952 [Warning] Access denied for user '<username>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-03-10 11:45:17 37180893952 [Warning] Access denied for user '<username>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-03-10 11:46:27 37180893952 [Warning] Access denied for user '<username>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This was a working server before I started upgrading FreeBSD.  I haven't done anything to change the permissions on any of the databases or files, in fact, the only things that I *did* change are the operating system and database engine - and I would have ***expected*** an "upgrade" to be transparent to the data!!

---

**EDIT**

I reviewed the output of `mysql_upgrade` and see there were a lot of errors related to the *sys* database.  I don't know if these are related, or what I can or should do about them:

```
Phase 3/7: Fixing views from mysql
sys.host_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.host_summary_by_file_io
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_file_io_type
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_stages
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_statement_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_statement_type
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_schema
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.innodb_lock_waits
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_by_thread_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_file_by_bytes
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_file_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_wait_by_bytes
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_wait_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.latest_file_io
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_by_host_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_by_host_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.memory_by_user_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.memory_global_total
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_global_total' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.metrics
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.global_status' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.processlist
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.ps_check_lost_instrumentation
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.global_status' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.ps_check_lost_instrumentation' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_index_statistics
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_table_lock_waits
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.metadata_locks' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.schema_table_statistics
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_table_statistics_with_buffer
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_tables_with_full_table_scans
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.session
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.session' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.session_ssl_status
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.status_by_thread' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
sys.statement_analysis
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_errors_or_warnings
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_full_table_scans
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_runtimes_in_95th_percentile
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_sorting
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_temp_tables
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_file_io
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_file_io_type
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_stages
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_statement_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_statement_type
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.wait_classes_global_by_avg_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.wait_classes_global_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.waits_by_host_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.waits_by_user_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.waits_global_by_latency
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$host_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$host_summary' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_by_host_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_by_host_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_by_user_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_by_user_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_global_total
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_global_total' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$processlist
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$processlist' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$ps_schema_table_statistics_io
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$schema_table_lock_waits
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.metadata_locks' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$schema_table_lock_waits' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$schema_table_statistics
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$schema_table_statistics_with_buffer
Error    : Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$session
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$session' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$user_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$user_summary' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
Error    : Corrupt
```

---

**EDIT 2**

***N.B.*** In both of these edits, the "OK" tables are removed to cut the size of the text in the question.

I re-ran `mysql_upgrade` again because the search results I found for "*mysql_upgrade Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted*" all seem to indicate such problems are fixed by running `mysql_upgrade`.  (I had to run `mysql_upgrade -p --force` because without the `--force` parameter it just said "*This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 10.2.13-MariaDB*")

Now I've got a different set of error messages that are equally opaque.  (The sequence `invalid table(s) ... to use them` in each case below can be expanded to `invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them` - I had to do these replacements to fit the 30000 character question length limit.)

```
Phase 3/7: Fixing views
sys.host_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.host_summary' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_file_io
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.host_summary_by_file_io' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_file_io_type
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.host_summary_by_file_io_type' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_stages
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.host_summary_by_stages' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_statement_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.host_summary_by_statement_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.host_summary_by_statement_type
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.host_summary_by_statement_type' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_schema
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_bytes does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_schema' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_bytes does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.innodb_lock_waits
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.innodb_lock_waits' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_by_thread_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.io_by_thread_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_file_by_bytes
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_path does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.io_global_by_file_by_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_file_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_path does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.io_global_by_file_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_wait_by_bytes
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.io_global_by_wait_by_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.io_global_by_wait_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.io_global_by_wait_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.latest_file_io
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_path does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.latest_file_io' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_by_host_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_by_host_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_by_user_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_by_user_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.memory_global_total
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.memory_global_total' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.metrics
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.global_status' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.metrics' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.processlist
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.processlist' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.ps_check_lost_instrumentation
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.global_status' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.ps_check_lost_instrumentation' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_index_statistics
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.schema_index_statistics' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_table_lock_waits
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.metadata_locks' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.schema_table_lock_waits' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_table_statistics
Error    : FUNCTION sys.extract_schema_from_file_name does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.schema_table_statistics' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_table_statistics_with_buffer
Error    : FUNCTION sys.extract_schema_from_file_name does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.schema_table_statistics_with_buffer' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.schema_tables_with_full_table_scans
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.schema_tables_with_full_table_scans' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.session
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.session' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.session_ssl_status
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.status_by_thread' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.session_ssl_status' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statement_analysis
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.statement_analysis' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_errors_or_warnings
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.statements_with_errors_or_warnings' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_full_table_scans
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.statements_with_full_table_scans' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_runtimes_in_95th_percentile
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.statements_with_runtimes_in_95th_percentile' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_sorting
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.statements_with_sorting' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.statements_with_temp_tables
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_statement does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.statements_with_temp_tables' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_file_io
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary_by_file_io' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_file_io_type
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary_by_file_io_type' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_stages
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary_by_stages' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_statement_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary_by_statement_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.user_summary_by_statement_type
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.user_summary_by_statement_type' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.wait_classes_global_by_avg_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.wait_classes_global_by_avg_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.wait_classes_global_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.wait_classes_global_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.waits_by_host_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.waits_by_host_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.waits_by_user_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.waits_by_user_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.waits_global_by_latency
Error    : FUNCTION sys.format_time does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.waits_global_by_latency' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$host_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$host_summary' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_by_host_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_by_host_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_by_user_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_by_user_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$memory_global_total
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_global_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$memory_global_total' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$processlist
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$processlist' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$ps_schema_table_statistics_io
Error    : FUNCTION sys.extract_schema_from_file_name does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$ps_schema_table_statistics_io' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$schema_table_lock_waits
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.metadata_locks' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$schema_table_lock_waits' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$schema_table_statistics
Error    : FUNCTION sys.extract_schema_from_file_name does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$schema_table_statistics' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$schema_table_statistics_with_buffer
Error    : FUNCTION sys.extract_schema_from_file_name does not exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$schema_table_statistics_with_buffer' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$session
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.events_transactions_current' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$session' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
sys.x$user_summary
Error    : Table 'performance_schema.memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' doesn't exist
Error    : View 'sys.x$user_summary' references invalid table(s) ... to use them
Error    : Corrupt
```

I tried running `mysqlcheck -r sys -p -v` and it tells me

```
Enter password:
Processing databases
sys
sys.sys_config
Error    : Table '    sys.sys_config' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
```

Is this the root of my problem?  If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: yes, I did run `mysql_upgrade` - and taking another look at the results, I see there were a lot of errors in `Phase 3/7: Fixing views from mysql` related to tables in the `sys` database with error messages like `Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted` - I will add the error messages to my question.

Comment: Another good idea would be to revert to the previous version first and verify whether that would work for you. On FreeBSD pkg should write the package names added/removed to `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, reverted the database server and restored the data from my backup.  At least now my system is working again, and I can investigate the problem with less stress.